# Environment variables in TeamSite

Tags: rest, environment-variables, teamsite

Is there any option to maintain environment specific variables in TeamSite? We're making REST API call to get user detail and REST API domain vary by environment. One option is to keep API domain in web.config and based on domain in URL, fetch domain specific values from web.config file. Is there any better way to maintain environment specific variables in TeamSite?

**TeamSite version: 20.2.0.5**